# How do i send DOS commands to my Receipt printer via COM1?

Tags: printing, cmd, serial-port, command, hex

How do i send DOS commands to my Receipt printer via COM1?

Im currently devoloping a Cash register software, and i ran into an issue using the receipt printer. i need to be able to send hexidecimal commands to the printer via DOS.

so far i've tried to do the following.

Open CMD
input Copy con: com1
input a hexidecimal number
press Ctrl + Z
press Enter

this according to what i've read should send the hexidecimal number as a command to he printer. but instead it just sends the number as a string and prints out the text.

some info on the printer im using:
TPG A794 receipt printer.
a manual on the printer can be found here:
http://www.cognitivetpg.com/downloads/A794%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf

hope someone can help me out, as i've tried everything, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not enter the Hex-Code. You need the ASCII-Code in Decimal. 
For example: to write 0xF, you must turn it into decimal (15)
after `copy con: com1`press 'ALT' (keep it pressed) while you enter the decimal value with three digits ( 015 ), then release 'ALT'.
Continue with the next value, if it is a command with more than one HexNumber.
When finished, press Ctrl-Z.

It may be easyer to use, if you write your "commands" to a textfile, then you can copy them to com1:
for example:

```
copy linefeed com1:
```

(I have no serial device to test, but it should work)

I tried it with

```
copy con bell.txt
```

Then I entered **007** (= 0x07, which is a Bell), **Ctrl-Z**. This gives a textfile with lenght = 1 byte

```
Type bell.txt
```

will then beep.

**EDIT**
"1B" is the Code for a so-called "Escape-Sequence" (a multi-byte-command) "70" is the command itself and it needs three parameters (n, p1, p2). So the complete Sequence is 5 bytes long. You will have to replace "n", "p1" and "p2" with proper numbers. You will find those in the manual of your serial device ("1B" is the Code for a so-called "Escape-Sequence" (a multi-byte-command) "70" is the command itself and as you describe it, it needs three parameters (n, p1, p2). So the complete Sequence is 5 bytes long. You will have to replace "n", "p1" and "p2" with proper numbers. You will find those in the manual of your serial device (http://www.cognitivetpg.com/downloads/189-9200250C.pdf), Page 69.  P1 and P2 seem to describe the time, the drawer needs to open/cose) N describes which drawer you talk to.

**EDIT2**
create one file per command. eg. "open1.bin" "close1.bin" etc. Create them as described in my first answer. You should first try with "simple" commands (one-byte-commands) to verify, that this works ok. To execute the commands, send them to com 1 using `copy open1.bin com1:`. For multibyte commmands create them with `copy con: file.txt` Enter first value while you keep "alt" pressed, release "alt", press it again and keep it pressed for the second value and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!
cant tell you how much i appritiate it!
you just saved me like 500$ if not more! :D

Comment: I got 1 more issue that i simply cant understand. im hoping maybe you know what to do with it
for an Example i need to enter the following code to the printer to make it open my cash register. 1B 70 n p1 p2.
my problem is, i dont understand what n p1 and p2 is.. n seems to be used alot and it seems to be binary, but im not able to figuer out how to put it into the command.

Comment: edited my answer, as it is too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks alot for this. im still struggeling to understand how i should input this into CMD, is there any chance you could give me an Example on what to put into CMD?
i really appritiate your help here, wouldnt have come this far without it.

Comment: create one file per command. eg. "open1.bin" "close1.bin" etc.

Comment: does this file need to contain open/close or just a number value ? im not sure im completly understanding this. im rather new to dos programming :p i appritiate you hanging in there with me :)

Comment: Your printer will only accept accept numbers. For Example the ooen-command is described in the manual as "1B n p1 p2". If n=0(hex) then the first drawer 1 will open, if n=2(hex), drawer 2 will. p1 and p2 are timing values, if you don't find any values in the manual, you will have to try. So the complete Command to open drawer 1 will be (timing values are guessings) "0B 30 A0 A0" - the decimal values of these chars are "27 48 160 160" With the descripton in EDIT2 put those 4 values to a file. That file should then be exactly as big as 4 bytes and look like this: `←0áá`

Comment: you can then send this commandfile to your printer using `copy /b file txt com1` (you need the `/b` for "binary", else your printer will show ←0áá on the paper - what is not, what you want...)

Comment: sorry, i forgot a byte. The complete command is  "0B **70** 30 A0 A0" - and of course it is **5** bytes long

Comment: Thanks man! i will try this tomorrow when im back home with my setup! you truely are a lifesaver! appritiate this ALOT

Comment: i used the command you gave me, and it worked perfectly! Thanks sooo much for this help. Much appritiated.